# setlocale() has no effect on macOS

Tags: c, macos, locale

I am using [the example program for `setlocale()` from cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale) on a macOS 10.14.6 system, however, the output is not localized. I checked that the return value from `setlocale()` is not `NULL` and tried a variety of locale specifications in an attempt to get a decimal comma, such as `de`, `de_DE`, `de_DE.utf8`.

Why does this not work?

How can I find out why the output isn't affected, and whether it is because of incorrect locale names?

On the same OS, locale changes from Python do appear to work (as in that they affect number printing by C code running within the same process). Thus I do not think that the problem is that this locale is not supported.

---

The full program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wchar.h>
 
int main(void)
{
    // the C locale will be UTF-8 enabled English;
    // decimal dot will be German
    // date and time formatting will be Japanese
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE.utf8");
    setlocale(LC_TIME, "ja_JP.utf8");
 
    wchar_t str[100];
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    wcsftime(str, 100, L"%A %c", localtime(&t));
    wprintf(L"Number: %.2f\nDate: %ls\n", 3.14, str);
}
```

Comment: Try `"de_DE.UTF-8"`

Comment: Re “I checked that the return value from `setlocale()` is not `NULL`”: When I wrap the `setlocale` calls in `printf("%s\n", setlocale(…));` and build and run the program on Mac OS X 10.14.6, the output is “en_US.UTF-8”, “(null)”, “(null)”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Indeed. That's not `NULL` though, which was quite confusing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't realize that it was legal to pass a null pointer to printf for a `%s` and it will print `(null)` ... It must have been a real null pointer then.

Comment: @Szabolcs: It is not defined by the C standard, and I would not use that in general code; I would test the `setlocale` return value and print my own message. But macOS libraries handle it, so it worked well enough for this debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the terminal, [`locale -a`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=locale) can be used to see all available locales.

On my system<sup>1</sup>, `locale -a | grep de_` yields the following results

```
de_CH
de_DE.UTF-8
de_AT.ISO8859-1
de_AT.UTF-8
de_AT.ISO8859-15
de_DE.ISO8859-15
de_CH.UTF-8
de_DE-A.ISO8859-1
de_CH.ISO8859-15
de_DE.ISO8859-1
de_CH.ISO8859-1
de_AT
de_DE
```

`setlocale` returns `NULL` in the event that the combination of arguments do not make sense. On my system<sup>1</sup>,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{
    // the C locale will be UTF-8 enabled English;
    // decimal dot will be German
    // date and time formatting will be Japanese
    char *all = setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    char *num = setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE.utf8");
    char *tim = setlocale(LC_TIME, "ja_JP.utf8");

    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", all, num, tim);

    wchar_t str[100];
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    wcsftime(str, 100, L"%A %c", localtime(&t));
    wprintf(L"Number: %.2f\nDate: %ls\n", 3.14, str);
}
```

outputs

```
en_US.UTF-8
(null)
(null)
Number: 3.14
Date: Thursday Thu May 12 08:35:37 2022
```

Using locales from the prior list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{
    // the C locale will be UTF-8 enabled English;
    // decimal dot will be German
    // date and time formatting will be Japanese
    char *all = setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    char *num = setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE.UTF-8");
    char *tim = setlocale(LC_TIME, "ja_JP.UTF-8");

    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", all, num, tim);

    wchar_t str[100];
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    wcsftime(str, 100, L"%A %c", localtime(&t));
    wprintf(L"Number: %.2f\nDate: %ls\n", 3.14, str);
}
```

outputs

```
en_US.UTF-8
de_DE.UTF-8
ja_JP.UTF-8
Number: 3,14
Date: 木曜日 木  5/12 08:37:51 2022
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that this is tested on macOS 10.15.7. Results may differ on macOS 10.14.6. You should not blindly trust examples you find, including mine here, but rather check your own system's locales.

[`locale`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=locale) has been available since Mac OS X 10.4.

Comment: FYI, `de_DE-A.ISO8859-1` appears to be new; it does not appear for `locale -a | grep de_` on my 10.14.6 system. Otherwise, that output and the sample program output appear the same, except my system is currently printing a different time than yours did.